# Is there a XmlTextReader.ReadContentAsBase64 analog for JsonTextReader

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON containing a binary property with a very large value:

```
{
    "NormalStringValue" : "test",
    "NormalIntValue" : 1,
    "LargeBinaryValueInBase64": "AQB...."
}
```

The standard Newtonsoft `JsonTextReader.ReadAsBytes` reads the value of a `LargeBinaryProperty` at once so a large byte array is allocated. I want to avoid this.
For `XmlTextReader` there is a `ReadContentAsBase64(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)` method which can perform buffered reading of a BASE64 content.

Is there any library that implements such a method for JSON data?
Or maybe it can be achieved with Json.NET?