# Pass Base64 encoded string using JsonTextReader value as new stream

Tags: c#, json, http, json.net, filestream

We are consuming large JSON streams from an HTTP Post request. The goal is to stream the incoming body as JSON using JsonTextReader and extract the embedded base64 encoded binary files to disk. In XML, an equivalent method might be 
XMLReader.ReadElementContentAsBase64Async.

Using JSON.NET, as we iterative how do we send the each item of the encodedImages array into a FileStream without holding the whole string in memory.

Example JSON Object:

```
{
    "company":"{clientCompany}",
    "batchName":"{clientBatchName}",
    "fileType":"{clientFileType}",
    "encodedImages":[
        "{base64encodedimage}",
        "{base64encodedimage}",
        "{base64encodedimage}"
    ], 
    "customFields":{
        "{clientCustomField1}":"{clientCustomValue}",
        "{clientCustomField2}":"{clientCustomValue}",
        "{clientCustomField3}":"{clientCustomValue}",
        "{clientCustomField4}":"{clientCustomValue}"
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think so.  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46365304/3744182) was never answered, which seems to have led to Issue #1462 [Add buffered reading of binary data to JsonTextReader #1462](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1462) getting opened.

Comment: @dbc It appears that that issue was raised 1 hour ago and the question was asked about 3wks ago. Maybe our threads combined will raise awareness :-)

Comment: You could always add a comment to Issue #1462 indicating you would like that ability also.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your problem can be addressed in two parts: 1) How to parse and process the JSON in a memory efficient way, and 2) How to perform base-64 decoding iteratively

1) Memory efficient JSON parsing:

Assuming you can use the Newtonsoft JSON.net library, the `ReadAsBytes` or `ReadAsBytesAsync` methods of the [`JsonReader`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader.htm) class are going to be your best friends, as they allow iterative stream-based processing which will allows you to minimize your memory footprint during JSON parsing and processing. To avoid writing low-level parsing code for your entire document, you might consider writing a `JsonConverter` implementation for the `encodedImages` node of your example.

2) iterative base-64 decoding

Most base-64 decoding implementations decode a string in its entirety. Support for iterative buffered decoding (as support by the `ReadElementContentAsBase64Async` method of `XmlReader`) requires some state to be maintained. Digging into the implementation of that class, you will find the internal [`Base64Decoder`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Xml/System/Xml/Base64Decoder.cs) class which does precisely what you need.

Comment: JsonReader.ReadAsBytes[Async]() reads entire value into a bytes array. Almost the same does  JsonConverter. The question says: "how do we send the *each item* of the encodedImages array into a FileStream *without holding the whole string in memory*".